# Procedure to setup a server with CA service to certify the PDF that my organization issue

Tags: pdf, ca, ocsp

I am working in a organization which the documents are our products while the validity is very important.
We are switching to use PDF with electronic signature.
My question is that is it possible to setup a windows server with the CA service to make a OCSP service to every documents. If so, can you give me some reference or procedure to set up and add the certificate to signatures and procedure to revoke the document if needed(preferably with cmd prompt)?

Thanks